# convert multi line string to single line

Tags: string, scala, multiline

Consider the following snippet

```
val myString =
  """
    |a=b
    |c=d
    |""".stripMargin
```

I want to convert it to a single line with delimiter `;`

```
a=b;c=d;
```

I tried

```
myString.replaceAll("\r",";")
```

and

```
myString.replaceAll("\n",";")
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: use `\n` instead of `\r`

Comment: Tried doesn't work

Comment: it works for me :) see my answer below

Comment: You may need both "\r\n" if you are on Windows - it still thinks it's working with a teletype, and if it it doesn't end a line with carriage return, you terminal will start typing over the previous line ...

Comment: Yes right but what if I use it is on Unix box after it is deployed.on local it is windows but deployment  on unix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with `\n` and it works

```
scala> val myString = """
     | a=b
     | c=d
     | """.stripMargin
myString: String =
"
a=b
c=d
"

scala> myString.replaceAll("\n",";")
res0: String = ;a=b;c=d;

scala> res0.substring(1, myString.length)
res1: String = a=b;c=d;
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Using `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `"\n"` allows this to work on Windows

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652402/5205022

```
"""
  |a=b
  |c=d
  |""".stripMargin.linesIterator.mkString(";").trim
```

which outputs

```
;a=b;c=d
```

or using single whitespace `" "` as separator

```
"""
  |Live long
  |and
  |prosper!
  |""".stripMargin.linesIterator.mkString(" ").trim
```

which outputs

```
Live long and prosper!
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the first Google result at "Scala multiline to a single line" and the question is pretty general. It may be reasonable to add an implicit way:

```scala
implicit class StringExtensionImplicits(s: String) {

    def singleLine: String = {
      singleLine('|')
    }

    def singleLine(marginChar: Char): String = {
      s.stripMargin(marginChar).replace('\n', ' ')
    }

}
```

Now you can:

```
logger.info(
  """I'm a so long log entry that some devs who like vim don't like me.
    |But you can help them to keep patience.""".singleLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myString.split("\n").filter(_.nonEmpty).mkString("",";",";")
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to find how to create multiline strings:

```
val myString = "This is " +
               "my string"
```

which output is `This is my string`. You can also use s strings here to implement variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    val myString =
      """
        |a=b
        |c=d
        |""".stripMargin.lines.mkString(";")
```

`linesIterator` is deprecated since scala 2.11